# Long time between do event and handle it using jquerymobile/phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I develop an app using phonegap and jquerymobile/jquery.
During development I only had a virtual iOS device and now since I'm testing the app on a real device I see, that time between click on an element and handle this event is very long.
E.g if i Click on an icon a loader icon is shown but this icon first come in the moment the next page is final loaded (a very short time the loader is shown).

I develop with Javascript since a long time and always have focus on performant execution but this is very strange.

The App has got about 10 views in one HTML file. And on click on an element only show the next part of these file.

Does anyone know about solutions to solve "Bugs" like these?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tested on a non-developer mode device?  It's been seen before that from some devices, once they're in developer mode, input recognition latency can increase.  I had a very long conversation with another dev on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877419/what-are-common-sources-of-phonegap-with-jquery-mobile-performance-issues/7925211#7925211 about the issue. On my device (which is not in developer mode) the pages, transitions, everything worked great.  Very responsive.  On his, there was about a 1 second delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The click delay on iPhones is a feature used to distinguish between clicks and scrolls. When you bind to the `click` event iOS waits approximately 300ms to decide whether you were clicking an object or trying to scroll the page.

You can use jQuery Mobile's `vclick` event which fires much faster however you will probably run into situations where the `vclick` event is fired off twice in a row which can result in multiple elements being clicked. Here is some sample code of how to use `vclick` events and only capture the event triggered first:

```
$(function () {

    //setup a function to check if a vclick event has fired within the last 500ms
    function check_vclick () {

        //if a vclick event has fired in the last 500ms then return false
        if (do_vclick == false) return false;

        //otherwise set a flag to disallow vclicks for 500ms
        do_vclick = false;

        //setup a timeout to allow vclicks in 500ms
        setTimeout(function () {
            do_vclick = true;
        }, 500);

        //return true so the event handler knows it's ok to run its code
        return true;
    }

    //setup a flag to allow/disallow vclick events from firing
    var do_vclick = true;

    //bind an event handler to the vclick event for an element
    $('#link_id').bind('vclick', function () {
        if (check_vclick()) {
            //run the code associated with the element, if it's a link referencing a pseudo-page on the same HTML document, you can do something like this
            $.mobile.changePage($(this.href));
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a link to the documentation for `$.mobile.changePage()`: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/methods.html

Here's a link to the documentation for `vclick` (notice the notes under the virtual mouse event section): http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/events.html