# possible way to make jquery mobile faster?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm working on mobile web page using jquery mobile, it seems to have almost every required feature but I found it's very slow. Especially, during transition the whole performance is not acceptable. Since I didn't change any configuration about jquery mobile, is there any possible way to make it faster?

I'm testing on iis 8.0 + asp.net MVC 4.0 razor, jquery mobile 1.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are common sources of PhoneGap with jQuery Mobile performance issues?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877419/what-are-common-sources-of-phonegap-with-jquery-mobile-performance-issues)

Comment: This has been discussed many times on Stack Overflow, take a look at the above link, it's got some good pointers. There are many more questions/answers that can help you. Also, why are you using jQuery Mobile 1.0? The current stable release is 1.1.1 and they're getting ready to release 1.2. Version 1.1.1 offers a lot of performance increases over version 1.0.

Comment: Thanks. I realized there were so many discussions about it. And I saw that it is faster after update to version 1.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Microsoft's Task Parallel Library on the backend to divvy up the work your controllers need to do. Running in parallel will make it faster. Also, try removing all transitions from JQM. It's less sexy, but will provide more responsiveness on page transitions.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
      //Set your global init settings here
      //This is the setting you are looking for!      
      $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';

      //I personally use some other settings, such as:
      $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
      $.mobile.useFastClick  = false;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me more? Where should I put this code, every page or layout, etc?

Comment: @Sanghoon put it in a file on its own (i normally call it config) and make sure it is loaded before JQM

Comment: @Sanghoon put the parallel code in your controller actions. Put the mobile init code in your _Layout.cshtml, since this is usually called first.